# tomcat vulnerabilities discussion

Tags: java, security, jsp, tomcat7

I have a web application with Tomcat 7.0.42. I have recently found on my server files I havent uploaded. these hacker files allow anybody to create files on my server.

I'd really like to figure out how they have got access to my server. In my web application I have a form to interact with users, but all fields are restricted with regular expression and I use prepared statements to deal with the database.

Moreover I uploaded a version of my web application which ONLY displayed information, I removed all forms and I didnt let any type of interaction with users. I also changed passwords. But files still appearing

I would like to discuss possibles vulnerabilities and solutions to them:

- Remove write permissions on tomcat webapps folder once I have uploaded my war?
- May my code be corrupted?

Any help would be so much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Option 3: they got in through another way totally unrelated to Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

As Mark pointed out, the easiest way to get into a Tomcat server it's by accessing the Tomcat Manager with a week or default password.

Make sure it's not publicly available, you have a strong password and check your JSP code for web vulnerabilities.

Once you have been hacked, you could already be backdoored, either at code level or by some rootkit in your server. Check your web logs, what commands had been executed recently, and IMHO a "rm -rf /" to make sure everything is wiped out.

Ignacio.

Comment: what is backdoored? The code is not a problem: I uploaded a version with just one page to display information but they continued accessing my server

Comment: Backdoored means that the attacker has planted a software to access whenever he/she wants into the affected device/software.

A backdoor could be planted either in your code (you should make a checksum or diff the files in order to see if there's any unwanted change) or in your server.

Check your tomcat logs and perhaps you'll see something interesting. Depending on the attacker profile it might left traces of his activities and entering with the same vulnerability over and over or he could make a more advanced attack covering his actions and 'installing' a backdoor to enter whenever he wants

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the Tomcat security docs http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html

First check to see if the Manager application is present and if you have configured a user with a weak password for that app.

Looking at the access log is usually my next port of call.

As @Grimby rightly pointed out, Tomcat might not be the way they are getting in.